# Why this question is locked?

Tags: discussion

Why is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available) closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't lock it, but I suspect it is locked because it is an "infinite list of X", not really a question that can be *answered* in any meaningful sense.

I believe it is correctly locked for that reason.

Comment: it is hardly infinite.also what about this(http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) and this(http://askubuntu.com/questions/198/what-video-players-do-you-recommendhttp://askubuntu.com/questions/198/what-video-players-do-you-recommend) and this(http://askubuntu.com/questions/4246/what-are-some-good-php-editors).   all of them are community wiki questions which cannot be answered in any meaningful sense(all answers are correct).

Comment: At least backup tools question asks for comparisons, not just huge list. If someone gives answer with good comparison, it is possible to select best answer. From list of games you can't select answer to that question ("List all possible games, one per answer").

Comment: but the other two ask for good php editors and video players you can't select a best answer.

Comment: @Alaukik That question was locked for the reasons given by @Jeff already. However, the other questions in your comments have a lot shorter of a list and haven't been massively updated. The amount of updates that question was getting became overwhelming and no longer meaningful. The other community wiki's offer a shorter list to redeem themselves to some extent. They're meaningful because their list is *a lot* more finite than the Gaming one.

Comment: This is the most optimistic take on the Linux gaming landscape I've ever heard.  A possibly infinite list of games, even! Huzzah!  And to think I used to hear there were *no* games on Linux.  (Yes, I'm ignoring the actual controversy here in order to enjoy the delightful irony.)