# How often do questions get answered?

Tags: discussion, new-users

To all those newbies of Ubuntu, does your query get solved in most easy steps?

Most of the time, I have seen questions are either left unanswered or are linked to duplicate questions in comments. Ubuntu versions make difference. So they are not exactly duplicate questions as they differ from older versions.

Does reputation points work really great or does it mislead users in answering or trusting the solution?

Ask Ubuntu works very well but the questions of newbie users, who get migrated from Windows, are not answered in easy steps.

Newbie users need answers in much easy step. If they get tough solution, won't those users go back to other systems?

Is Ask Ubuntu making answer in easy step to newbie?

Comment: I'm locking this because the post is in an edit-war. The current version is sane and has a good answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> To all those newbie of ubuntu, does you get your query solved in most easy step ?

*Most easy step* is a relative measure. I find installing software from terminal *most easy*. But, some  other users may not agree with me. So, my answer and their answer may look different. They may provide a GUI step. And for newbie, if is also relative. Some may find terminal way better, some may prefer GUI way. So, **there is no absolute measure of most easy steps.**

> Most of the time, I have seen questions are either left unanswered or are linked to duplicate questions in comments. Ubuntu versions make difference. So they are not exactly duplicate questions as they differ from older versions.

The duplicateness of a question is determined by the Moderators, but most of the time by the Ask Ubuntu users. **5** votes are required by the users to close a question *(if not moderation action is taken)*. So, you can't just say, they are all wrong. If you have any specific objection about a closing of a question, discuss that issue in [meta site of Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/). There are many examples of such questions. Just [look at this query](https://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=why%20this%20question%20is%20closed). Here is some example, for the answer being easy.

- [why is my question closed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3666/why-is-my-question-closed)
- [Why was question 4389 closed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/357/why-was-question-4389-closed)
- [Why this question is locked?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/977/why-this-question-is-locked)

there are may examples of such questions and those are answered in good

> Does reputation points work really great or does it mislead users in answering or trusting the solution?

You don't need to look at the reputation of the answerer. You simply need to follow the steps. Some users are really new, so they don't have enough reputation. But, that doesn't mean, their solutions are bad. In early time in AskUbuntu, I have one answer accepted where a much higher reputed user gave an answer. Also, acceptance depends on OP. Otherwise, reputation points work good, ***if not great***

> Newbie users need answers in much easy step. If they get tough solution, won't those users go back to other systems?

That really depends on the newbies. Some *newbies* are really like winning over a tough situation and they stick to Ubuntu. Some may go back to older systems. We don't want to lose them but, We really can't help beyond our ability, Sorry.

> Ask Ubuntu works very well but the questions of newbie users, who get migrated from Windows, are not answered in easy steps.
>
> Is Ask Ubuntu making answer in easy step to newbie?

I think, **Yes**, Ask Ubuntu making answers in as easy step as possible.

**A note on easiness and AU answerers and users:**
Well, Ask Ubuntu is run (meaning working) by voluntary and free help of many of the Ubuntu users. They are not paid for this service. So, we can't blame them for uneasiness of solutions. **Sometimes there is no easy solutions either.** For example, If a user ask, **I liked the Windows File Explorer, How do I run this on Ubuntu?**. There is no easy solution to this question, I think.

Comment: Now thats good answer @anwar shah

Answer (score 7):

#### We are human beings. We can't solve every problems.

Don't think new users are idiots. They know how to ask a question. New user's questions may not be simple and answerable.

we have lives outside Ask Ubuntu. We help users voluntarily. So its not our 'fault' if something is unanswered. Try asking support for something you use, other than Ubuntu, in real life. You'll know how good we are doing

Comment: Add to it that we have lives outside Ask Ubuntu. We help users voluntarily. So its not our 'fault' if something is unanswered. Try asking support for something you use, other than Ubuntu, in real life. You'll know how good we are doing.

Comment: And look at this question if your answer doesn't get answered: http://askubuntu.com/q/131149/39869

Comment: @Mahesh,@Emerson : feel free to add it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Are you saying that is Ask Ubuntu is not helping new users?

This is totally wrong. Sometime ago, I was also a new user and there are many good people. You earn this reputation by answering question to new user and to old user also..

1. Ask Ubuntu says that you need to do some home work before you ask any question.
2. Answer to your question depends on how you ask.
3. If a same question is already asked in Ask Ubuntu and answered, only then will your question be marked as duplicate.
4. It is not true that only new users don't get any answer. Even I have posted some stupid and good questions which don't have any answer even now.
5. And if you ask good question, you will get reputation from upvotes on that question. If your answer is good and accepted by the user, you will also be awarded with reputation.
6. Ask Ubuntu never forces you to accept any answer. It's upon you to accept the answer that helps you resolve your problem.

For more details, please read [how to ask questions on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

> Most of the time i have seen questions are left unanswered or link to
>   duplicate leaving comments. UBUNTU Versions make difference so it
>   won't be duplicated as same question ask in older version.

Let's try to answer that query in parts.

Well, if they are unanswered as you have seen, you are **free and highly encouraged** to answer them in best possible way. Sometimes commenting makes sure that they are addressed, next to get answered.

Ubuntu versions does make difference but mostly in Window managers and desktop environments. The basic building blocks remains same and equally configurable to newer versions, hence coined as "Duplicate".

If a new user asks *How to spell Ubuntu*, then I would consider answering them in most easy way possible as anybody here would.

But logically speaking, if the OP was able to research about where and how to get help (Ask Ubuntu in this case), then to some extent it is assumed OP is equally qualified to know what are **similar** or **Duplicate** questions.

This duplicate process is highly avoided and highlighted by the Ask Ubuntu system itself. For example, try asking a New Question and see the previously similar asked question below them or Q's with the highest **Resemblance** .

As you are familiar, I guess so, Ask Ubuntu QA system is contributed and maintained by volunteers like you and me in free time or being human time. :)

And AFAIK, the migrated user gets best possible help not even provided by their previous counter-OS-Support by allowing you to run both of them. Refer [Eliah Kagan's answer for that](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3812/63025).

It's all about how you can contribute to Ubuntu in most suitable way possible (nobody is forcing you), unlike Paid Support, where your question holds true to last full-stop.

Comment: well explained. But me looking to make newbie user much comfort with ubuntu. I don't want them to go back to any other system. want to spread ubuntu as much as we can

Comment: That actually is [Bug No.1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1) to solved by Ubuntu :)

Comment: yup its very true. But here at ASK-UBUNTU we can make it more easier task to them isnt !